An interesting alternating sum $\sum _{k=0}^n\left(-1\right)^k\binom{k}{m}$
i was messing around with some combinatorial type sums and started thinking about a certain alternate sum that is the following : for $(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ what would be the value of :
$$S_{m,n}=\sum _{k=0}^n\left(-1\right)^k\binom{k}{m}$$
First of all , if we remove the $(-1)^k$ coefficient we get the famous sum :
$$\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{k}{m}$$
Combinatorially we can think of this as counting the ways to pick  $m+1$ elements from the set $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ , following the value of the highest element in our subset of $m+1$ elements. Hence , fatally , we have :
$$\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{k}{m}= {{n+1} \choose {m+1}}$$
Now my question is , is there a closed form for $S_{m,n}$ and if yes , is there a combinatorial way to think about it .

These sums look as if they are going to be negative when $n$ is odd.  Ignoring that, I think you get OEIS A059260 which is essentially  OEIS A059259 backwards.

A generating function for the $S_{m,n}$ terms for a fixed positive $m$ is given by $\dfrac {(-1)^m}{(1-x)(1+x)^{m+1}}$ (for $m=3$ for example you should get OEIS A002623 that is $-1 + 3 x - 7 x^2 + 13 x^3 - 22  x^4 + O(x^5)$)

so basically there is no closed form for it ?

I can prove that there does not exist a hypergeometric closed form for $S_{m,n}$. Roughly, this means $S_{m,n}$ cannot be written as a finite algebraic expression involving factorials. This is exactly what Gosper's algorithm was designed to determine. Running the following Maxima code returns NO_HYP_SOL, which means there is no such solution. Try it online!
load(zeilberger)$
out: Gosper((-1)^k * binomial(k, m), k)$
fortran(out);

However, for each fixed $m$, viewing $S_{m,n}$ as a function of $n$ alone, I can give a closed form in terms of $n$. Even though this is a summation, it is still a closed form, because it is a sum of $m+2$ terms, and $m$ is constant.
$$
(-1)^nS_{m,n}=\frac{(-1)^{n-m}}{2^{m+1}}+\sum_{k=n-m}^n \frac 1{2^{n-k+1}}\binom{k}{n-m}.\tag1
$$
Here is how I came up with this formula. Equivalently, I show how to get a closed formula for $A_{m,n}=|S_{m,n}|$, which is given by
$$
A_{m,n}=(-1)^n S_{m,n}=\sum_{k=m}^n(-1)^{n-k} \binom km.
$$
First, I gave a combinatorial interpretation to $A_{m,n}$. As you mentioned, $\sum_{k=m}^n \binom km =\binom{n+1}{m+1}$ can be seen to count subsets of $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ with cardinality $m+1$, where the $\binom km$ term counts subsets with maximum element $k+1$. Analogously, we can interpret $A_{m,n}$ as a signed count of $(m+1)$-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$, where a subset with maximum element $k+1$ is counted with a sign of $(-1)^{n-k}$.
Here is the clever part. Consider a particular $m$-element subset $S$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. The idea is to group together all of the $(m+1)$-elements in the alternating summation whose $m$ smallest elements are precisely the set $S$. We will then compute the total contribution of each group to the sum $A_{m,n}$. Two examples should help here, both with $n=6$ and $m=2$.

Let $S=\{2,4\}$. Then the $3$-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,7\}$ whose two smallest elements are $S$ are $\{2,4,5\}$, $\{2,4,6\}$, and $\{2,4,7\}$. The total contribution is $1-1+1=+1$. (For example, $\{2,4,5\}$ has a sign of $+1$, because the maximum is $k+1=5$, and $(-1)^{n-k}=(-1)^{6-4}=+1$).

Let $S=\{1,3\}$. Then the $3$-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,7\}$ whose two smallest elements are $S$ are $\{1,3,4\}$, $\{1,3,5\}$, $\{1,3,6\}$, and $\{1,3,7\}$. The total contribution is $-1+1-1+1=0$.


For each $S$, the total contribution of the sets containing $S$ is always an alternating sum like $(1-1+1-1+\dots)$, so the total contribution is always $1$ or $0$, according to whether the sum stops with $+1$ or $-1$. If you do the bookkeeping carefully, you can see that the contribution of $S$'s group is
$$
\frac{1+(-1)^{n-\max S}}{2}.
$$
So, $A_{m,n}$ is equal to the sum of the above quantity over all $S\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $|S|=m$. By splitting that fraction into $1/2$ and $(-1)^{n-\ell}/2$, we split this into two sums over $S$. The first sum is the sum of $1/2$ over $S$, which is just $\frac12 |S|=\frac12 \binom nm$. The second sum is the sum of $\frac12(-1)^{n-\max S}$ over $S$; but this corresponds exactly to the combinatorial interpretation of $A_{m-1,n-1}$. That is, we have proved
$$
A_{m,n}=\frac12\left[\binom nm + A_{m-1,n-1}\right]\tag2
$$
From $(2)$, you can directly derive $(1)$. For example, if you take $(2)$, and expand $A_{m-1,n-1}$ into two parts according to $(2)$, $A_{m-1,n-1}=\frac12[\binom{n-1}{m-1}+A_{m-2,n-2}]$, and substitute that into $(2)$, you get
$$
A_{m,n}=\frac12\binom nm+\frac14\binom {n-1}{m-1}+\frac14 A_{m-2,n-2}
$$
You then keep iterating this until you get down to $A_{0,n-m}$, and use the base case $A_{0,n-m}=\frac{1+(-1)^{n-m}}{2}$.

great answer , any insight on how u came up with the closed forms ?

@AdamBoussif I remembered how I derived the closed forms, see edit.
